# Unresolved reference: synthetic

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

When I updated

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
```

I can't use view ids in my layout files direct in kotlin code, and it fails to import

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.my_layout_file
```

is it removed in the new version because view binding has been introduced?